# How to calculate the hours between two times with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, time

I am trying to calculate the hours between two times.

Below is where I am currently but this code fails in two ways.

**1).** I need `.Hours` to output time in decimal.

*(e.g one and half hours should output 1.5 and 15mins should be 0.25).*

**2).** Calculation currently does not treat values for time as `time`.

*(e.g 23:00 to 2:00 should equal `3` and **NOT** `-21` as currently).*

---

**HTML**

```
<input class="Time1" value="10:00" />
<input class="Time2" value="12:00" />
<input class="Hours" value="0" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
 $(function () {
     function calculate() {
         var hours = parseInt($(".Time2").val().split(':')[0], 10) - parseInt($(".Time1").val().split(':')[0], 10);
         $(".Hours").val(hours);
     }
     $(".Time1,.Time2").change(calculate);
     calculate();
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Easy way is if you get a negative value, add 24 hours to it and you should have your result.

```
var hours = parseInt($(".Time2").val().split(':')[0], 10) - parseInt($(".Time1").val().split(':')[0], 10);

// if negative result, add 24 hours
if(hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/1/

Getting the minutes as a decimal involves a bit more as you can see in thsi fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/2/

```
function calculate() {
     var time1 = $(".Time1").val().split(':'), time2 = $(".Time2").val().split(':');
     var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10), 
         hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
         mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
         mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10);
     var hours = hours2 - hours1, mins = 0;

     // get hours
     if(hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;

     // get minutes
     if(mins2 >= mins1) {
         mins = mins2 - mins1;
     }
     else {
         mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
         hours--;
     }

     // convert to fraction of 60
     mins = mins / 60; 

     hours += mins;
     hours = hours.toFixed(2);
     $(".Hours").val(hours);
 }
```

Comment: simple but effective thanks. Any idea how I can calculate minutes as decimal?

Comment: or either `hours +=(hours < 0 ? 24 : 0)`.

Comment: @techfoobar This is working great with one exception: When duration is 23-24 hours result is still negative. Can't understand why because of your if statement? http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/3/

Comment: There was a logical error in the hours if condition. Corrected version is here: http://jsfiddle.net/44NCk/4/

Answer (score 2):

```
function timeobject(t){
  a = t.replace('AM','').replace('PM','').split(':');
  h = parseInt(a[0]);
  m = parseInt(a[1]);
  ampm = (t.indexOf('AM') !== -1 ) ? 'AM' : 'PM';
  return {hour:h,minute:m,ampm:ampm};
}

function timediff(s,e){
  s = timeobject(s);
  e = timeobject(e);
  e.hour = (e.ampm === 'PM' &&  s.ampm !== 'PM' && e.hour < 12) ? e.hour + 12 : e.hour;
  hourDiff = Math.abs(e.hour-s.hour);
  minuteDiff = e.minute - s.minute;

  if(minuteDiff < 0){
    minuteDiff = Math.abs(60 + minuteDiff);
    hourDiff = hourDiff - 1;
  }

  return hourDiff+':'+ Math.abs(minuteDiff);
}

difference = timediff('09:10 AM','12:25 PM');  // output 3:15
difference = timediff('09:05AM','10:20PM');  // output 13:15
```

Comment: updated my answer hope you will understand this easily

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(function () {
     function calculate() {
         var time1 = $(".Time1").val().split(':'), time2 = $(".Time2").val().split(':');
         var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10), 
             hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
             mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
             mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10),
             seconds1 = parseInt(time1[2], 10),
             seconds2 = parseInt(time2[2], 10);
         var hours = hours2 - hours1, mins = 0, seconds = 0;
         if(hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
         if(mins2 >= mins1) {
             mins = mins2 - mins1;
         }
         else {
             mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
             hours--;
         }

         if (seconds2 >= seconds1) {
                seconds = seconds2 - seconds1;
         }
         else {
                seconds = (seconds2 + 60) - seconds1;
            mins--;
         }

         seconds = seconds/60;
         mins += seconds;

         mins = mins / 60; // take percentage in 60
         hours += mins;
         //hours = hours.toFixed(4);
         $(".Hours").val(hours);
     }
     $(".Time1,.Time2").change(calculate);
     calculate();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an HTML Code

```
 <input type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" value="12:00">
 <input type="text" name="end_time" id="end_time" value="10:00">
 <input type="text" name="time_duration" id="time_duration">
```

Here is javascript code

```
function timeCalculating()
  {
    var time1 = $("#start_time").val();
    var time2 = $("#end_time").val();
    var time1 = time1.split(':');
    var time2 = time2.split(':');
    var hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10), 
    hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
    mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
    mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10);
    var hours = hours2 - hours1, mins = 0;
    if(hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
    if(mins2 >= mins1) {
        mins = mins2 - mins1;
    }
    else {
      mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
      hours--;
    }
    if(mins < 9)
    {
      mins = '0'+mins;
    }
    if(hours < 9)
    {
      hours = '0'+hours;
    }
    $("#time_duration").val(hours+':'+mins);
  }
```

Comment: Hi, could you please extend the script with decimal output of duration? For Example 08:24 as 8,4 h. Another good option would be to have the breaktime. Let me say the break time is given as 01:06 (1h and 6 Minutes) . Thank you.

Comment: Find your answer here 

<script>
timeCalculating();
function timeCalculating()
  {
    var time1 = "12:06";
    var a = time1.split(':')  + ' h';
    alert(a);
  }
  
  timeCalculating1();
function timeCalculating1()
  {
    var time1 = "12:06";
    var a = time1.split(':');
    alert(a[0] + ' Hours and ' + a[1] + ' Minutes');
  }
</script>